# Python find contours and draw contours function error

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, contour

I am currently working on a project detecting defects on an image. 
[image: image after I apply threshold function]

The contours are not connected...I don't know why they're discrete point

[image: contours]

Here is my code:

```
   ret, thresh1 = cv2.threshold(img, 95, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
   cnts= cv2.findContours(thresh1,cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)[-2]
   cv2.drawContours(img, cnts, -1, (255,255,0), 3)
```

Also the `len(cnts)` function isn't return the right number of white point...

Comment: your question is not clear. What do your mean by your contours are not connected? Can you upload sample images you are working with and specify what results you expect from findContours on them?

Comment: How do you know `len(cnts)` isn’t returning the right number? Or is this an assumption/guess?

Comment: Also is the first balck and white your original image because then what are defects in the image.

Comment: @KnightForked, I uploaded two images, one is after thresholding and one is after the draw contours function on the original image(Which is a bunch of points around the object I want to detect).

Comment: @barny Hi, Barny. Because for what I expected it should return 19 as there is 19 bright spot I want to detect. However, the function returns 33

Comment: Can you post high resolution image? Your images are not giving much information here as the contours you are detecting are pretty small.

Comment: Ah, expected - I don’t suppose `findCountours()` is making areas up just for the ’ fun’ of it. Most likely some of those 19 visible pixel areas isn’t fully connected, so some of them are two or more contours.

Comment: Post your original thresholded image. The one you show is drawn in Matplotlib and the spots are not fully black and white. We want to see the image saved from cv2.imwrite(). Also use cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL in your findContours to get the outside contours only around each spot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that find contours is picking holes as well. Try this one out and see if it fixes your problem.

```
ret, thresh1 = cv2.threshold(img, 95, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
cnts= cv2.findContours(thresh1,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)[-2]
cv2.drawContours(img, cnts, -1, (255,255,0), 3)
```

Comment: @Luna Liu, so the change here is that instead of RETR_LIST you are only looking for RETR_EXTERNAL (external) contours.